# Entiries disappearing from calender after a few months

Tags: calendars

I use my calendar daily and rely on it all the time. After a few months the details disappear from my calendar. Now in the last few days whenever I make an entry it just doesn't show at all, wondered if my space had been used.  When I go into settings and choose 'emails + accounts' to try to alter the amount of time the data is shown it says 'loading' then just goes back to the settings options.  Why is this so and how do I fix it?